# What should I do if the Class component of React cannot obtain the updated state in time?

Tags: web3-react

I have a piece of code like this.

```js
Modal.confirm({
    tilte: "title",
    content: (
        <>
            <input onChange={
                () => this.setState({ A: true });
            }></input>
            
            this.state.A && <div>text</div>
        </>
    )
})
```

The purpose is that after the input changes, `<div>text</div>` will be displayed, but it is found that state `A` cannot be obtained in time after the change, resulting in the content in `div` not being displayed. How can I modify it? ?

Answer (score 0):

Question:
You are using imperative `(Modal.confirm)` to display the `Modal`, and the `state` change does not trigger the `Modal` to re-render.
solution:

`Modal` can be displayed declaratively, for example:

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
 A: false,
 visible: false
  };
  handleClick = () => {
 this.setState({ visible: true });
  };
  render() {
 const { visible } = this.state;
 return (
   <>
     <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Show Modal</Button>
     <Modal
       visible={visible}
       onCancel={() => this.setState({ visible: false })}
     >
       <input onChange={() => this.setState({ A: true })}></input>
       {this.state.A && <div>text</div>}
     </Modal>
   </>
 );
  }
}
```

Extract the content displayed by `Modal.confirm` into a component

```js
class ConfirmContent extends React.Component {
  state = {
 A: false
  };
  render() {
 return (
   <>
     <input onChange={() => this.setState({ A: true })}></input>
     {this.state.A && <div>text</div>}
   </>
 );
  }
}

//
Modal.confirm({
  tilte: "title",
  content: <ConfirmContent />
});
//
```

Root cause: The update granularity of `React` is a fiber tree, such an imperative method often recreates a fiber tree (internally it will call `createRoot`, or `ReactDom.render`), your question That's when the update operation is triggered with a fiber on `fiber` tree1 (the `fiber` tree you created yourself in `App.tsx`), not with `fiber` on `fiber2` Update (the fiber tree you created with `confirm`), a component corresponds to a `fiber`, they belong to that fiber tree after they are passed a `createRoot` or `ReactDom.render`s